# Regex to match hyphen between two specific words surrounded by square brackets

Tags: regex, zabbix

I need to match the following with Regex

```
[zabbix-frontend]
```

I have started with the following, but I do not know how I can capture the hyphen - and the following word and bracket

```
^\[zabbix
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I have only tried this so far amongst other things, but cannot get a match on the words as above. `^\[zabbix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regular expression can be used to match only the string "[zabbix-frontend]":

`/\[zabbix-frontend\]/`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/\[(\w+)\-(\w+)\]/m
```

This will capture "zabbix" as one match and "frontend" as another match.
If you want to capture "zabbix-frontend" then use:

```
/\[(\w+\-\w+)\]/m
```